# request pointers on beginner DSP board for making an EQ simulating hearing aid prescription with TV sound

Tags: audio-processing, frequency-modulation, equalizer

I want to make an equalizer set to similar frequency cut-boost according to the results from the graph from hearing test, where an audiometrist will play tones of various frequencies at various volumes to check the hearing levels for various frequencies and then an 8-band equalizer graph will be programmed in the hearing aid according to the results.

Therefore, I would like to apply a similar audio effect to the Television audio such that my mom can have clearer sound of here TV dramas without cracking the volume to a very levels.

Please also share guidance on where I can buy the dsp boards and ship to India, was exploring Analog devices ADAU1401/ADAU1701 learning beginner boards as they appear to have simple and free graphical interface for programming the EQ in the board and have basic analog input and output pins as well.

I was considering purchasing for ebay US or UK, in case there are other simpler options for India that will also help me.

Comment: Hi! So Marcus provides a DSP-wise answer, as you have asked for so, however, I want to remind you that there's an alternative approach with analog equipment too. May be you can find very affordable second/third hand micro-hifi sets (from 90s, 80s) with some having 10-band graphic EQs. Now it can have a damaged radio, CD-player, or casette deck etc, all it must have is a functional line-in and speakers (of course). Assuming the EQ bands are sufficiently closer to your requirements, it will do your job. It doesn't need any programming; just electronics shopping and line-in connection. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

So, first off: ebay is *never* a good source for electronics. There's various large electronics distributors (digikey, mouser, farnell/element14…) in India, so that's really not a problem.

But: For prototyping, I'd strongly recommend you do *not* start with a DSP board. Start with your PC or laptop computer. The good thing about DSP is that it is really just applying math to samples, and it doesn't matter to the math at all which kind of processor applies these – as long as it's fast enough. For audio bandwidths, any modern microcontroller with a floating point unit will be fast enough for basic signal processing, and an 8-band equalizer is very basic. You *really* don't need an ADAU1401/1701. These are very high-speed, specialized, and thus hard-to-develop-for platforms that, again, are total overkill for an equalizer application like yours. And they are appropriately expensive.

So, start with implementing your equalizer on a PC/laptop. There's  *IIR biquad* filters that are typically used as low-latency, low-compute-overhead individual bandpass filters. If I remember correctly, people use RBJ's "[Audio EQ cookbook](https://webaudio.github.io/Audio-EQ-Cookbook/Audio-EQ-Cookbook.txt)"'s *peakingEq* with the 8 "peak" frequencies that the audiometrist would adjust as `f0`, calculating `w0`, `alpha`, `A` from the document based on that and your sound card's `Fs`. (If unsure, I'd try using 40 Hz, 80 Hz, 160 Hz, 320 Hz, 640 Hz, 1280 Hz, 2560 Hz, and 5120 Hz for `f0`. It's not like your mum will hear fine differences in a 12 kHz.)

All you need to do is implement `(Eq 4)` from the cookbook, in your software.

Once you can apply these biquad bandpass filters to samples from a recorded file, and weigh each of them (choose a different `A` for each of them), then sum them up, and write the result to a file that you can play back: Congratulations, your EQ works!

Now, replace writing to the output file with a library call that directly plays back through your computer's sound card. When that works, replace reading from the input file with a library call that directly captures from your computer's sound card. BAM! Live equalizer!

If you wrote that equalizer in a language that is *somewhat* efficient (C++, Rust, Go,… but it doesn't have to be assembler or anything. Most programming languages *are* fast enough. Maybe not start with Matlab or Python when processing individual samples ;) ) well, you're done. Buy a single-board computer like the popular raspberry Pi (doesn't need to be an expensive one! If your programming was efficient, then the RPi Zero would totally do!), and a USB sound card if the single-board computer doesn't have an analog audio in- and output. Compile your program for the OS that runs on the board, and make your mother proud and a bit happier about her TV.